# How do Wordpress plugins require a minimum Wordpress version to be installed?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, version

I've been trying to figure out how Wordpress plugins, both custom and available from the Wordpress website require a minimum version of Wordpress before allowing the plugin to be installed. I did read in the Wordpress docs that you can include a readme.txt file that specifies this, but I can't find it anywhere in code that does this. I believe this text file is just for display purposes but I'm not entirely sure. For example, if I were to create my own plugin that doesn't have this file, how do I determine the minimum Wordpress version in my plugin code? I've done quite a bit of Googling but just can't find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In the main PHP file of your plugin in the header section where you would normally add plugin name etc. There is an option `requires at least` see example below

```
**
 * Plugin Name:       My Basics Plugin
 * Plugin URI:        https://example.com/plugins/the-basics/
 * Description:       Handle the basics with this plugin.
 * Version:           1.10.3
 * Requires at least: 5.2
 * Requires PHP:      7.2
 * Author:            John Smith
 * Author URI:        https://author.example.com/
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       my-basics-plugin
 * Domain Path:       /languages
```

For more info visit [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This makes sense. If I don't see this in the main PHP file but I DO see it in the readme.txt file (downloaded from Wordpress.org) then is the required version honored in the readme.txt file instead?

Comment: In [This link](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header) it seems that not... {File Headers in readme.txt
Some plugins contain the readme.txt file which might contain look-a-like headers as well. Those files are not handled by WordPress but by third-party applications.}